# How do you overload the '<' operator to compare between objects of the same class?

Tags: c++

Right now I have a class item

```
   class Item{
        public:

            short p;        //profit
            short w;        //weight
            bool *x;        //pointer to original solution variable
            void set_values (short p, short w, bool *x);

    };
```

and I need to compare two different instances so that it checks the values of each one and returns either true/false

```
 if (Item a < Item b){
       //do something
 }
```

How can I do that? I've been reading cppreference but I don't really understand how to do it.

Comment: It depends on which attribute of the class you want to compare.

Comment: I want to compare p and w

Comment: `if (Item a < Item b){` - that line makes no sense in C++. What did you mean here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simply,

```
bool Item::operator<(const Item& other) const {
    // Compare profits
    return this->p < other.p;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To compare both the left hand side `p` and `w` with the right hand side `p` and `w` use the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    short p;
    short w;
    friend bool operator<(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.p < rhs.p && lhs.w < rhs.w;
    }
};
```

Comment: disregard my previous comment.  I didn't know that syntax was valid.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want to compare p, the code should look like this:

```
class Item {
private:
...
public:
    friend bool operator < (const Item& lhs, const Item& rhs) {
        return lhs.p < rhs.p;
    }
};
```

Comment: disregard my previous comment.  I didn't know that syntax was valid.

Comment: It is OK, I was also confused just now.@xaxxon

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the trivial code did make the code silly.@Blastfurnace